# Counting the number of struct nested in another struct?

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I'm not sure I'm doing the best design here…

I'm coding an app where I have categories of chapters nesting chapters. All the values will be hardcoded. For exemple :

```
struct Chapter1 {
    struct Category1{
        let name = "#1"
        let content = "Lorem Ipsum"
    }

    struct Category2{
        let name = "#2"
        let content = "Lorem Ipsum Ipsum"
    }

    struct Category3{
        let name = "#3"
        let content = "Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, I want to return the number of Category in a numberOfSectionsInTableView. How can I count those? Is there a way? Or maybe my design isn't the right one?

And then, I'll need to pass the struct name through a segue… Is it possible?

For the moment, the solution I found is very inelegant. In the Chapter1 struct, I put an array with "Category1", "Category2", etc… It's not optimum! And I didn't found a solution to do that :

```
var x = "Category1"
var nameOfTheSelectedCategory = Chapter1.x.name
```

Don't even know if it's possible but it may be a solution... I also tried with a switch but I've got the same issue…

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused about what is a type and what is a value. You have defined four types, but what you need are two types, and some instances (values) of those types.

Here are the types you need:

```
struct Chapter {
    let categories: [Category]
}

struct Category {
    let name: String
    let content: String
}
```

And here is an array value containing one value of type `Chapter`, which contains three values of type `Category`:

```
let chapters: [Chapter] = [
    Chapter(categories: [
        Category(name: "Data Structures", content: "structs, classes, enums, tuples, etc."),
        Category(name: "Algorithms", content: "sorting, searching, calculating, etc."),
        Category(name: "Programs", content: "Flappy Bird, Microsoft Word, etc."),
    ])
]
```

You might define your table view data source like this:

```
class MyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    let chapters: [Chapter] = [
        Chapter(categories: [
            Category(name: "Data Structures", content: "structs, classes, enums, tuples, etc."),
            Category(name: "Algorithms", content: "sorting, searching, calculating, etc."),
            Category(name: "Programs", content: "Flappy Bird, Microsoft Word, etc."),
            ])
    ]

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return chapters.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return chapters[section].categories.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CategoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        let category = chapters[indexPath.section].categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.category = category
        return cell
    }

}
```

If the segue is connected out of the cell in the storyboard, then the cell itself is the sender, so you can handle it like this:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "CategoryDetail" {
            let cell = sender as! CategoryCell
            let categoryDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CategoryDetailViewController
            categoryDetailViewController.category = cell.category
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice! Let's go that way !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider approaching your data model a little differently, take a look at doing something like this

```
class Chapter {
    let name: String
    var sections: [Category]

    init(name: String, sections: [Category]){
        self.name = name
        self.sections = sections
    }
}
struct Category {
    let name: String
    let content: String
}

var newChapter = Chapter(name: "One", sections: [Category(name: "#1", content: "Lorem Ipsum")])

newChapter.sections.append(Category(name: "#2", content: "Test"))
```

You can further extend your model if you need to support multiple chapters by making `self.data = [Chapter]` and then in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` return `self.data.count` and in `numberOfRowsInSection` return `self.data[section].sections.count`.

Comment: Thanks ! Rob was faster (that's what she said!)

Comment: No worries. His was more thorough.

Comment: https://theweinblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/thats-what-she-said.jpg?w=286&h=215